# compare to arrays of objects and update key in angular 6 typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

```
listOne: [
{ 
  id: 1,
  compId: 11,
  active: false, 
},
{ 
  id: 2,
  compId: 22,
  active: false, 
},
{ 
  id: 3,
  compId: 33,
  active: false, 
},
]

listTwo: [
{ 
  id: 1,
  compId: 11,
  active: true, 
},
{ 
  id: 2,
  compId: 33,
  active: false, 
},
]
```

I have two json, here how to compare with **compId** key and update the active key in **listOne** from **listTwo** if **compId** is same.

In AngularJs I have tried with below this related link [for AngularJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40510798/compare-to-arrays-of-objects-and-update-key-in-angular)

But how to integrate with Angular 6 with Typescript.

And expected output is 
`listOne: [
{ 
  id: 1,
  compId: 11,
  active: true, 
},
{ 
  id: 2,
  compId: 22,
  active: false, 
},
{ 
  id: 3,
  compId: 33,
  active: false, 
},
]`

Comment: use `listOne.forEach...`

Comment: Have you tried implementing it similar to the linked question? `for` loops and array prototype methods work just the same in typescript

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare to arrays of objects and update key in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40510798/compare-to-arrays-of-objects-and-update-key-in-angular)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
// Iterate over list one
for(let item of this.listOne){
    // Check if the item exist in list two
    if(this.listTwo.find(i=>i.compId==item.compId)){
        // Update key
        item.active = this.listTwo.find(i=>i.compId==item.compId).active;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use map and filter like this

```
listOne = listOne.map(item => {
       let exist = listTwo.filter(c=>c.compId == item.compId)[0];
       if(exist != undefined){

           item.active = exist.active;
           return item;
       }else{
           return item;
       }
    });
```

```js
let listOne= [
{ 
  id: 1,
  compId: 11,
  active: false, 
},
{ 
  id: 2,
  compId: 22,
  active: false, 
},
{ 
  id: 3,
  compId: 33,
  active: false, 
},
]

let listTwo= [
{ 
  id: 1,
  compId: 11,
  active: true, 
},
{ 
  id: 2,
  compId: 33,
  active: false, 
},
]

//let arr3 = [];

listOne = listOne.map(item => {
   let exist = listTwo.filter(c=>c.compId == item.compId)[0];
   if(exist != undefined){
       //item.id = exist.id;
       item.active = exist.active;
       return item;
   }else{
       return item;
   }
});

console.log(listOne);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried and got solution for the question.
So we need to iterate two **for** to check each data like below.
And need to replace as need

```
for (const s of listOne) {
              for (const r of listTwo) {
                if (s.compId === r.compId) {
                  s.active = r.active;
                  break;
                }
              }
            }
```

- I have already mentioned the link which the answer available for **AngularJS**. but i'm looking for Angular 2+ Typescript.